# Use, in another project, a variable saved in a project (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, variables

I have a project named ***project1***, where I take a big .txt file (around 1 GB). I make a list that has each line of the text as elements, with the following code:

```
txt = open('<path>', 'r', encoding="utf8")
lista = list(txt)
```

And then I edit the items in the list, which is not important for my question.

I need to use the variable ***lista*** in another project (***project2***), but i don't want to import it in the following way

```
from project1 import lista
```

because by doing that I have to run all the code in ***project1*** to get the text in the .txt file and to edit the list.

So my goal is to use ***lista*** without having to run code that takes time, since ***lista*** will always be the same.

### IMPORTANT NOTES

1. I can't just print it in project1, copy the output and paste it in project2 to use it as a variable, because the list is way too long.
2. One way I thought about that was to save ***lista*** as a string in a .txt file (let's call it ***lista.txt***), open the .txt file in ***project2*** and, in some way, tell python that the string in ***lista.txt*** is actually a list. Example to understand better:

In project 1

```
file_text = open('<path>\\lista.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8")
lista = ['<string_1>', '<string_2>', ..., '<string_n>']
file_text.write(f'{lista}')
file_text.close()
```

In project 2

```
file_text = open('<path>\\lista.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8")
list_as_string = file_text
def string_to_list(input_string):
    #way to transform the list_as_string into the original "lista" variable, which is a list
    #return list
string_to_list(list_as_string)
```

3. ***IMPORTANT***: The way that I described looks to complex to me, so it was just an idea, but I'm sure there are better ways (maybe there is a way to save a python variable as a file that keeps information like its type and the directly import it in a project as a variable of that type, in this case a list)

Comment: Are you looking for [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) or [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#examples)?

Comment: I don’t actually know how to use those libraries, so I don’t know: every good solution is accepted

Comment: Thanks! If you want to write the answer i will accept it @kendfss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest that you use `txt.readlines()` instead of `list(txt)` in order to get the lines unless every line in the file contains a single character. In Json/Pickle; `dump/dumps` enable you to save an object to an open file (you could save the list to a file) or obtain the source/bytes, respectively, that would be saved in a writable-file-object; `load/loads` allows to restore the content from the corresponding dump. Personally I would just make a new list using the file's path or encapsulate the code in the other script to make it less slow on import.